# About Installation

Tags: installation

I am a new user to Ubuntu, presently using Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit. I can't install any software from the Ubuntu Software Center. it Says "Available From Universe Source" And there is button for "use this source" not for Install

Answer (score 1):

Open Software Source from dash and mark Universe and Multiverse.

Now open a Terminal from dash and enter this command:
`sudo apt-get update`

When it is complete, you can install those softwares from Software Center.